# Name for this common stock scream? (not the Wilhelm scream)

Tags: sound-effects

**NO NO NOOOO AAaAaAaAAAAARGH**

I first came across this scream when I viewed Timesplitters 2 (when players get set on fire), and while it's nowhere near as popular as the tediously overused Wilhelm scream (or female/reverse variants), I have occasionally come across it since.

Just that I can remember, it's in No Vaseline by Ice Cube.

(first at 0:40)

and in this ad for detergent

(at 0:30)

I've tried googling this but have never gotten anything back apart from the Wilhelm scream.

Any sound/movie buffs know the origin?